# Image on pie graph with highcharts

Tags: graph, charts, highcharts, data-visualization

I am looking for a graph library that is highly customizable. I found Highcharts and loved it. I am trying to create a pie chart that has images on it. Something like this image

[image]

but I am not sure how to do it with highcharts. can anyone help me. Is this possible with highcharts ? if not can you please suggest any other graphs where I can get this output?

Comment: You can use [pie chart](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-basic) and render images by [renderer](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer.image);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible using Highcharts to add custom image to chart using default API's `renderer`. (API reference: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer.image)

In `load` chart event you could add custom images to chart and to keep chart responsive - in `redraw` event you could update the images.

Simple example http://jsfiddle.net/dh6e15op/1/

Comment: so what happens when the percentage is too small . http://jsfiddle.net/mahesheu/82zLt4xb/

Comment: This is only simple example how to add images using renderer. There  should be provided more complex logic for images placement for this to work with small percentages. It is possible to add images outside pie slice if slice is too small or place it in tooltip (useHTML: true and add <img> tag in HTML using formatter - API: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.formatter)

Comment: Can you please help me with the formula also. i tried using few but didnt work it well. if i have more than 2 sectors in the circle.  @Kacper Madej please help  http://jsfiddle.net/uq9kyon6/2/

Comment: If you will get center of slice you will be able to place image over there. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/71uoLz0k/ Size of images is based on radius of pie series, but if there will be more images, then images might be too large, so you would need to calculate size of images from radius and angel of slice.